# Bootstrap Multinomial regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to bootstrap a simple multinomial regression in R, and I am getting an error:

> Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'd' not found

What is really strange is that I am using the same code (adjusted to this particular problem) as in a tutorial for boot package [at Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/bootstrapping.html), and that same code also worked when I am using different function (like lm()). For sure, I am doing something stupid, but I do not see what. Please, if anyone can help, I would appreciate a lot.

This is an example:

```
require(foreign)
require(nnet)
require(boot)

# an example for multinomial logistic regression
ml = read.dta('http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta')
ml = ml[,c(5,7,3)]

bs <- function(formula, data, indices) {
    d = data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
    fit = multinom(formula, data=d)
    s = summary(fit)
    return(list(fit$coefficients, fit$standard.errors))
}

# 5 replications
results = list()
results <- boot(
    data=ml, statistic=bs, R=5, parallel='multicore',
    formula=prog~write
)
```

Comment: Please post the output of `traceback()` in your question.

Comment: I did some sleuthing, and this might lead to a solution: there is something going in with the environment (seen by printing str(fit) from inside the `bs`-function. It is set to global, as you pass a formula and formula's have the enivronment in which they were created (see ?formula). Don't see how to fix it now though.

Answer (score 2):

The error happens in the `summary()` part, also the object returned by `multinom()` does not have `coefficients` and `standard.errors`. It seems, that `summary.multinom()` in turn calculates the hessian from your data, `d`, which for some reason (probably a scoping issue) cannot be found. A quick fix is to add `Hess = TRUE`:

```
bs <- function(formula, data, indices) {
  d = data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
  fit = multinom(formula, data=d, Hess = TRUE)
  s = summary(fit)
  return( cbind(s$coefficients, s$standard.errors) )
}

# 5 replications
results = list()
results <- boot(
  data=ml, statistic=bs, R=5, parallel='multicore',
  formula=prog~write
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Multinomial logistic regression returns a matrix of coefficients using the `coef()` function. This differs from a `lm` or `glm` model which returns a vector of coefficients.

```
library(foreign)     # read.dta()
library(nnet)        # multinom()
require(boot)        # boot()

# an example for multinomial logistic regression
ml = read.dta('http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta')
ml = ml[,c(5,7,3)]

names(ml)

bs <- function(formula, data, indices) {
  d = data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample
  fit = multinom(formula, data=d, maxit=1000, trace=FALSE)
  #s = summary(fit)
  #return(list(fit$coefficients, fit$standard.errors))

  estimates <- coef(fit)
  return(t(estimates))
}

# enable parallel

library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
clusterExport(cl, "multinom")

# 10000 replications
set.seed(1984)

results <- boot(
  data=ml, statistic=bs, R=10000, parallel = "snow", ncpus=2, cl=cl,
  formula=prog~write
)

# label the estimates

subModelNames <- colnames(results$t0)
varNames <- rownames(results$t0)

results$t0

estNames <- apply(expand.grid(varNames,subModelNames),1,function(x) paste(x,collapse="_"))

estNames

colnames(results$t) <- estNames

# summary of results

library(car)

summary(results)

confint(results, level=0.95, type="norm")
confint(results, level=0.95, type="perc")
confint(results, level=0.95, type="bca")

# plot the results

hist(results, legend="separate")
```